# Problema para abrir arquivo

Tags: php, html, mysql

Quando busco um arquivo .txt para importar me retorna os avisos

> Warning: fopen(Clientes.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in /var/www/html/sistemas/help-desk/processa/proc_letxt.php
>   on line 9
>
> Warning: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   /var/www/html/sistemas/help-desk/processa/proc_letxt.php on line 12
>
> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   /var/www/html/sistemas/help-desk/processa/proc_letxt.php on line 23

segue codigo:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

//local do arquivo

if (isset($_FILES['arquivo'])) {

    $arquivo = fopen($_FILES['arquivo']['name'], "r");

    // le as linhas do arquivo
    while (($linha = fgets($arquivo)) == true) {

        // divide os dados com separador "|"
        $parte = explode("|", $linha);

        // execulta query bd
        /*$sql = "INSERT INTO clientes (nome, cpf_cpnj) VALUES ('" . $parte[0] . "', '" . $parte[1] . "', '" . $parte[2] . "')";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);*/

        echo "<br>"."CNPJ: " . $parte[0] . "<br>" . "IE: " . $parte[1] . "<br>" . "Nome: " . $parte[2] . "<br>" . "E-mail: " . $parte[3] . "<br>" . "Fone: " . $parte[4] . "<br>" . "CEP: " . $parte[5] . "<br>" . "Logradouro: " . $parte[6] . "<br>";
    }
    fclose($arquivo);
} else {
    echo "erro";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O caminho do arquivo está no índice `tmp_name`.

O índice `name` retorna apenas o nome original do arquivo.

Basta trocar `name` por `tmp_name` nesse trecho:

```
$arquivo = fopen($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], "r");
```

Há outros pontos pertinentes mas prefiro me abster em comentar a fim de evitar dispersar a atenção ao foco principal.

Consulte: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php